# Normally open capacitive sensor with MOSFET is closing relay, how can I make it open?

Tags: mosfet, sensor, latching-relay

Would love some help here, I know next to nothing about electronics.

I've been asked to fit a normally open (NO) [capacitive sensor](https://uk.rs-online.com/mobile/p/capacitive-proximity-sensors/4438106/) to a [MOSFET](https://uk.rs-online.com/mobile/p/mosfets/5410553/) to operate a relay.

My problem is it is working backwards to the way I need it to.

I have a 24V supply to the relay +ve, the mosfet source is connected to the relay -ve.
Drain is connected to ground.
Gate is connected to the sensor, and I have a resistor from the sensor/gate to ground.

When the sensor detects an object it goes to 24V, and the MOSFET is then closing the relay which is activating a pump.  But I need the opposite result, when it detects an object it needs to open the relay and turn off the pump.

The task was to replace a NPN-NC sensor with a PNP-NO sensor.  Knowing nothing about MOSFETs I read that this would require switching from an n-channel one to a p-channel one.  I guess I didn't understand that p-channel MOSFETs can be enhancement or depletion.  So I think I've got a MOSFET that does the same as the previous one did, hence the logic is now backwards from what I wanted as the sensor is switched.

Unfortunately I do not have time to find another MOSFET, order and test it.  This has to be operational today.  Is there anything I can do with what I have?

Comment: Our text-to-schematic converter is out of commission so please **draw a schematic**. Do realize that most relays have normally open and normally closed contacts, maybe you could just use the other contacts?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie That would be ideal. I'm using an Omron g2rv-sr700, but I do not see anything in the datasheet about switching it from one mode to another. Am I unfortunately using a relay that cannot?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Further from previous reply... Ok, so the relay has 3 outputs, presumably there is a common one always used, and using either common with the 2nd, or common with the 3rd, will result in either a closed action or an open one. So whichever way round I've got it now I just need to switch one of the outputs over to the unused 3rd one?  Apologies, like I said I know nothing about electronics!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way, without the mosfet.

[image]

The sensor, capable of switching 200 mA, can easily drive the relay's 12.6 mA coil.

The 'NC' contact of the relay is used to turn off the pump.